# Como quitar el label de boostrap que viene por defecto

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando una tabla responsive de boostrap pero deseo quitar estos label que se crean automaticamente.
[image: I want to remove this]

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de plantilla de bootstrap estás usando para crear la tabla? Te recomiendo que la menos agregues el código HTML con el que estás trabajando para que sea mas reconocible el problema y recomendarte alguna solución.